# Pandas read_csv does not load a comma separated CSV properly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, kaggle

Now,I analyze Titanic challenge of Kaggel.
My code is this:
[image: code]

But my ideal output　is: 
[image: ideal output]

So,in my last code is

```
df["Age"].fillna(df.Age.median(), inplace=True)
```

and error happens

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'Age'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9763f0a9951c> in <module>()
----> 1 df["Age"].fillna(df.Age.median(), inplace=True)

/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
  1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3541 
   3542             if not isnull(item):
-> 3543                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3544             else:
   3545                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/Users/XXXi/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'Age'
```

I use `sep=','` so I really cannot understand why this code cannot separate  in each comma.How can I fix this?

I followed one answer,but error happens (I do not know why)
[image: error]

My data is [image: data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attention!**

The main issue was downloading the data. If you run a problem of loading and processing the Kaggle Titanic Dataset, you may re-download the CSV from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle/3136/train.csv?GoogleAccessId=competitions-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1504012566&Signature=S8FiX0VJKSQ2DzaCXgRuYB8C%2FOX48HTYAuPjftqwH1UeB%2Fepifcd4AUfTYdZGJMISKJJwU%2Fyy0I8Yaz%2F3TgHkYyTbgpl9JTeJMZWHf7nQlgfCwNGtDLg067i83l4UDr8Q0pZcnPSaGkPBC0IqYk2L%2BfbLeluAzPR7Yrtepla7b8Er2gFBGiSgUF1NBUpX3v0n%2ByIn8g1mtgg7n9oAonPZkOv7WqOfChh53AKcvnXDdZL%2B%2BhHqt77MGhDsq%2Fmt5wP1G%2BeaqXqomFAyfuSImHDnhVUPOYMVcJx8KAQ6OtTqt8yr6x33%2BYzK87SbRgwml%2FBj9Y01SHMRLFf8skeEqTVpA%3D%3D) and re-run your program.

---

You can pass `delimiter=','`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Desktop/data/train.csv", delimiter=',')
print(df.head())

   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  \
0            1         0       3   
1            2         1       1   
2            3         1       3   
3            4         1       1   
4            5         0       3   

                                                Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  \
0                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0      1   
1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  38.0      1   
2                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0      0   
3       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0      1   
4                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0      0   

   Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked  
0      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S  
1      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C  
2      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S  
3      0            113803  53.1000  C123        S  
4      0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S  


print(df.columns)

Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
```

Next, you can create a mapping of sorts:

```
mapping = {'male' : 0, 'female' : 1}
```

And you'll call `pd.Series.replace`:

```
df.Sex = df.Sex.replace(mapping)
print(df.Sex)

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

Comment: According to pandas documentation `delimiter` is just alternative name for sep: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @StefanK From my experience, there have been cases where I got things working by using a combination of them, or changing one to the other. I think they're complements for each other, not replacements. Edit: Changed my answer slightly.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thx for ur answer.I followed ur message, but AttributeError happen.I updated my question, if u know something, please help me.

Comment: @user8385498 Run all my code dude. You only followed the mapping part.

Comment: I followed ur codes precisely, but same error happens(I found one mistake before codes)I updated my question, if u found some mistake,please tell me.

Comment: @user8385498 please use `df = pd.read_csv("Desktop/data/train.csv", delimiter=',')`, not `sep=','`. If there are any more problems, run `pip install --upgrade pandas` and try again.

Comment: I cannot believe it!!!I run pip install --upgrade pandas, and tried it again, but same error happen.Is there a problem in my csv file?I updated it.

Comment: @user8385498 Go to this link: https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-competitions-data/kaggle/3136/train.csv?GoogleAccessId=competitions-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1504012566&Signature=S8FiX0VJKSQ2DzaCXgRuYB8C%2FOX48HTYAuPjftqwH1UeB%2Fepifcd4AUfTYdZGJMISKJJwU%2Fyy0I8Yaz%2F3TgHkYyTbgpl9JTeJMZWHf7nQlgfCwNGtDLg067i83l4UDr8Q0pZcnPSaGkPBC0IqYk2L%2BfbLeluAzPR7Yrtepla7b8Er2gFBGiSgUF1NBUpX3v0n%2ByIn8g1mtgg7n9oAonPZkOv7WqOfChh53AKcvnXDdZL%2B%2BhHqt77MGhDsq%2Fmt5wP1G%2BeaqXqomFAyfuSImHDnhVUPOYMVcJx8KAQ6OtTqt8yr6x33%2BYzK87SbRgwml%2FBj9Y01SHMRLFf8skeEqTVpA%3D%3D and download again.

Comment: @user8385498 Lmao, congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

Your read_csv looks fine, the replace in the same line seems to be causing trouble.

Try to first read the csv as is into the variable df. This way your code will be cleaner.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/data/train.csv',sep=',')
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map( {'female': 1, 'male': 0} )
```

But you can leave the sep argument altogether as comma is standard delimiter

Alternatively do the cleaning with replace on a new line after you read the file into df and use 
 `inplace=True`:

```
df['Sex'].replace({'male': 0, 'female': 1}, inplace=True)
```

**General advice:**

Kaggle webpage supports script sharing and commenting in kernel section.
Try to look at it to see how you can go about the analysis if you are stuck somewhere:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/kernels

Comment: thx, ur comments.Your means,
df= pd.read_csv("Desktop/data/train.csv",sep=',',inplace=True, regex=True).replace("male",0).replace("female",1) ,right?

Comment: But using this code,I got an error,
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-670579237ebd> in <module>()
----> 1 df= pd.read_csv("Desktop/data/train.csv",sep=',',inplace=True, regex=True).replace("male",0).replace("female",1)

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'  ,
do i misunderstand ur message?

Comment: I edited my original answer... do the cleaning on new line

Comment: Ur message means

Comment: df= pd.read_csv("Desktop/data/train.csv",sep=',',inplace=True, regex=True).replace("male",0).replace("female",1)
df.cleaning(inplace=True, regex=True)

Comment: Try just the two lines as presented. Or what coldspeed advices